# Ideals invariant under translation of variables

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

I am interested in studying ideals of an infinite polynomial ring $k[\dots,x_{-2},x_{-1},x_0,x_1\,\dots]$ which are invariant under translation of variables, e.g. if $x_3^2x_1^3-x_2^4$ belongs to such an ideal, then also $x_{3+n}^2x_{1+n}^3-x_{2+n}^4$ belongs to it for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Symmetric ideals, namely ideals invariant under any permutation of variables, have been studied for example in [Nagpal and Snowden - Symmetric ideals of the infinite polynomial ring](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.13027) and [Aschenbrenner and Hillar - An Algorithm for Finding Symmetric Gröbner Bases in Infinite Dimensional Rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4439). However I can't find references for ideals invariant under more general actions on the variables (and in particular translations). Where can I find them, if there are?

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of Inc-invariant ideals, see [Juhnke-Kubitzke, Dinh Van Le, and Römer - Asymptotic behavior of symmetric ideals: A brief survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.03617.pdf) and references therein.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in ["Gröbner bases of ideals invariant under endomorphisms", by Vesselin Drensky and Roberto La Scala, Journal of Symbolic Computation
(2006), Issue 7, Pages 835-846](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717106000228). In your specific situation, the general theory might be able to say something particularly useful.